# Spring Cloud Function-suitable for REST API? How to access GET path params?

Tags: spring, aws-lambda, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, serverless

I'm new to WebFlux and Serverless. I'm trying to create a REST API as Serverless via AWS API gateway.

The flow would be API Gateway --> Lambda --> DynamoDB

In order to achieve the API flow, would the Spring Cloud Function be the best choice? I found [aws-serverless-java-container](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) does the job seamlessly(wrapper of converting the event to http request/response)

I've gone through the documentation on http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/single/spring-cloud-function.html and few examples found in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function.
But still, I'm not convinced on whether with Spring Cloud Function I would be able to achieve the API flavor.

```
@Bean
//How path or query params can be mapped?
public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> getEmployeeDetails() {
 // business logic goes here
}
```

In the above snippet, how to achieve the GET request/response model. If my endpoint has /{dept}/{employee}/{name}, how Spring cloud function accepts the path params in GET request?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: The way I think about this is, Spring Cloud Function is a function abstraction, and it should not know about RESTful APIs. You can use the AWS API Gateway to convert path parameters to a JSON object and then call the lambda function. In that way the function is agnostic about whether it is called as an API or a Message. Better design, more work.

Answer (score 4):

API Gateway wraps all data of the incoming request into an [APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.java) object, which has several attributes, like the request body, path and query parameters, or the HTTP method of the original request.
For your use case, you would get the three path parameters dept, employee, and name.

However, the problem is that [SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.java), which does the mapping between the incoming APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent and your function, currently only considers a request body, but no other parameters at all.

I hope that the developers will fix this in the future.
In the meantime, you could implement a modified version of SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler, which considers the required parameters.
I've written a small article, [which covers exactly this topic](https://masteringaws.blogspot.com/2019/01/spring-cloud-function-aws.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same mistake with this, the documentation prompts you to think that you can do this, but you can't. This is only an example from spring-cloud-function, and springboot function aws specific code doesn't have this feature implemented (as far I could see).

You can follow the default route, if you want to implement your application in lambda with spring: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/blob/master/samples/springboot/pet-store.

Or... If you want, you can try the hard way, but **attemption**: you are completely alone: https://github.com/arawn/building-serverless-application-with-spring-webflux.

This project himself implements ObjecMapper conversions and you can get the parameters from request: https://github.com/arawn/building-serverless-application-with-spring-webflux/blob/master/src/main/java/serverless/aws/springframework/http/server/reactive/SimpleAPIGatewayProxyServerHttpRequest.java

The trick from here is to create Path template in lambda with proxy (Path: '/{proxy+}') and request are delegated from aws mapper.

Good luck!

Comment: After analyzing cold start time with spring boot and along with spring-cloud-function, I've taken the route of using only java and aws-sdk libraries to achieve my use case. Using APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent from aws-lambda-java-events library to get the request information and sending the custom APIGatewayResponse object back to API gateway. I had to deal with all the HTTP status code manually in this case. Even with plain Java function, cold start takes 8 seconds with 512MB memory.